# How to join 3 table using Linq in asp.net pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have 3 table: Comments

```
Comment_ID int identity(1,1) constraint COMM_PK primary key,
Mess_Id int references [Messages](Mess_Id),
SentDate date,
Comment_content nvarchar(max),
Stud_Id int references Student(Stud_Id),
Staff_Id int references Staff(Staff_Id),
BySupervisor bit
```

Staff

```
Staff_Id int identity(1,1) constraint STAFF_PK primary key,
FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
Email nvarchar(max) not null,
[Role] nvarchar(50) not null,)
```

Student

```
Stud_Id int identity(1,1) constraint STUD_PK primary key,
FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
Email nvarchar(max) not null,
Supervisor_Id int references Staff(Staff_Id),
SecondMarker_Id int references Staff(Staff_Id));
```

How can I join 3 table above using Linq?. I want to select Fistname and comment conten of Staff if BySupervisor = true, select Firstname and comment conten of Student if BySupervisor = false.

Comment: if you want Linq, why not C# code?

Comment: Are you trying to join them or just doing a query?

Comment: What SQL query you're using?

Answer (score 0):

The query will look something like below. I assume that you map that tables to C# POCO classes.

```
var staffs = //get all from db (of course they are IQueryable)
var students = // get all from db
var comments = // get the comments from db
var result = comments.Select(x => new {
            FirstName = x.BySupervisor ? staff.First(s => s. StaffId == x.StaffId).FirstName : students.First(s => s.StudentId == x.StudentId).FirstName,
            CommentContent = x.CommentContent
        }).ToList();
```

Classes that iuse look somethink like below, the names may differ but the logic is the same.

```
public class Comment {
    public int StaffIf {get; set;}
    public int StudentId {get;set; }
    // others
}

public class Staff {
    public int StaffId {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    //others
}

public class Student {
    public int StudentId {get;set; }
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    //others
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look here?
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

I have modified slightly one of  the samples to add third join

```
     var q =
            from c in table1
            join p in table2 on c equals p into ps
            from p in ps
            join x in table3 on c equals x into sth
            select new {sth };

        foreach (var v in q)
        {

        }
```

Should be easy to apply this to your scenario